# Should I include occasional volunteering on my Linkedin profile?

Tags: linkedin, volunteering

I frequently help some non-profit organization on a voluntary basis, just to help their causes, although I don't belong to any volunteer association officially.

Among other things, I recently realized an artistic page for the website of a non-profit organization focused on LGBT rights. It might be used for a promotional campaign. For it's online and my name it's mentioned, might it include on my Linkedin profile?

If yes, how should I do that?

I cannot include it in the section "Organizations" for I don't belong to any volunteer association officially: is there any other way to show it?

Comment: Are you asking whether you should include it? Or are you asking how to use Linkedin to include it? Or both?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist both of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Include it in the volunteering or publications section.** You should consider including it on your resume as well.

> I recently realized an artistic page for the website of a non-profit organization

That sounds like official volunteering for me - even if you're doing it ad-hoc. Consider reaching out to the organization and asking about including the work on your resume if you want to be sure though. I'm sure they'll encourage you to list the experience.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot include it in the section "Organizations" for I don't belong
>   to any volunteer association officially: is there any other way to
>   show it?

Put it in the "Volunteer Experience" section.

As @Jay correctly points out, to do this:
"Add profile section" > "Background" > "Volunteer experience"

Comment: thank you, where can I find the "Volunteer Experience" section?

Comment: "Add profile section" > "Background" > "Volunteer experience"